# TrueCrypt mounting 3TB, not enough memory

Tags: memory, mount, truecrypt

I've been using Truecrypt 7.1a to mount all kinds of 2TB files before, but now I'm having trouble with a 3TB file.

On my laptop it shows an error that says: "Not enough memory to complete this operation". I cannot tell you the ID because the Windows event logs do not show an error for that time.

My laptop runs Windows XP Home and has **2GB** RAM and there is more than 1GB left (I just rebooted). When I do the same thing on my Windows XP Pro **500MB** RAM PC, there is no problem (nor is there a problem on a Windows 7 laptop with 4GB RAM).

My guess is that it does not have to do with memory after all, that it is just the error message it shows when any other error happens.

Any tips are welcomed.

*(the original error-message is: Für diesen Befehl ist nicht genügend Speicher verfügbar)*

I've increased the pagefile to 1250MB fixed but no change (the pc has 500MB pagefile).

Comment: When does the error message appear exactly? What happens just before the error message appears?

Comment: It may have something to do with the your virtual memory/paging file size which can be restricted via control panel settings and available disk space.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz after I specify the password and click `ok` (alternatively if I have mounted another file before and used 'cache password' immediately after clicking `mount`).

Comment: @martineau I've increased the pagefile to 1250MB fixed but no change (btw the pc has 500MB pagefile).